# What is the purpose of using static on methods?

Tags: methods, static

I'm wondering since the nature of all methods is an action (doing something to variables ) and since this action is the same for all instances of that class, then what exactly static is there for?

could it be there to protect changes to class instance method?(so the original method remain unchanged )instead of any specific function or am I wrong and changing the methods of instance class doesn't affect the method of a class?

Comment: There are loads of examples and explanations online. Here is one: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-static-method-program

Answer (score 0):

Static instance variables belongs to the class such variables are shared among the objects of that class, whereas non-static instance variables belongs to object of the class. Static member functions are used to access static instance variables (cannot access non-static instance variables).
Eg. Suppose you have a class Student with instance variables : rollno, name, percentage and numOfStud. Here, rollno, name and percentage should belong to object, hence, not declared static. However, numOfStud should be declared static as it is not the individual property of the real world object i.e. student, it is the property of the class. And numOfStud would be incremented as more objects of class Student are created. And it will be accessed using a static method of the class.

This is the significance of static. I hope that clarifies your doubt.